# How to generate a skp file from SkPicture, in skia?

Tags: skia

In skia, we can use SkPicture to record draw commands and then playback it, it works well.
I am wondering if there is some ways to generate a skp file from the SkPicture, so that I can use debugger.skia.org to analyze the draw commands.

I know , it's easy to capture the skp file from Chrome web page or android package. For my own rendering engine , if it's possible to get the skp file from SkPicture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is what [SkPicture::serialize()](https://skia-doc.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/doxygen/doxygen/html/classSkPicture.html#a7ed0a0b09d82480b55d89270e003463f) does. Take the Skia picture you want to write to a file, call serialize() on it, write the resulting SkData to a file with the .skp extension, and you should be able to open it in the Skia debugger.